# how to override code in git when pull code

Tags: git, tfs, git-svn

When I pull code from TFS server `git tf pull --deep`, I met a error as below:

```
git-tf: Checkout conflict with files:....
```

How to overrride code on local to get new code from server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To put your stuff away temporarily type
`git stash`

then pull again with
`git tf pull`

if you want your stuff back type
`git stash pop`